# How do I align a div container both vertically and horizontally on a page using CSS or CSS + jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, css, alignment, vertical-alignment

I'm sure this has been asked before, but all the questions I can find are far too complex. Really simply, how do I align a div container to the center and middle of a page both horizontally and vertically, so that it also stays there when the page is resized as well.

All I need is a blank browser window with a div that stays in the center of the screen when the window is resized, no matter what. Horizontal align is quite easy using `margin:auto` but it's the vertical align that seems to be troublesome.

A lot of 'solutions' require that there first be a set height that the div is floating in. I'm sure there's got to be a simpler way...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The flexbox way:

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/LcakLxx3/)** (Resize browser window))

### Markup

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
.container {
    width: 80vw;
    height: 80vh;
    display:flex;
    justify-content: center; /* align horizontal */
    align-items: center; /* align vertical */
    background: aqua;
}
.child {
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
    background: crimson;
}
```

Comment: Best solution I've seen yet. Any idea though how I can make text inside that child box align vertical and horizontal as well here: http://jsfiddle.net/kmgphegz/ I'll probably use this as a base and try to solve the text issue myself later.

Comment: Just add the code `display:flex;
    justify-content: center; /* align horizontal */
    align-items: center; /* align vertical */` in the child element - http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/kmgphegz/1/  or with little text http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/kmgphegz/2/

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks so much. That's perfect.!

Answer (score 1):

There are definitely a lot of way you can achieve this. Here is one of the way. I am using `position:absolute`.

```
 .center
{
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  margin:auto;
  border:5px solid black;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/P4RVD/428/)

Comment: This is very good except again, it doesn't really work if the text is variable height..... I wonder if the height can be set dynamically using jquery at all.. thanks anyway

Answer (score 1):

You can use `display: table-cell` and `vertical-align: middle` to achieve this.

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="content">
        blah blah
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
    display: table-cell;
    height: 100vh;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 100vw;
}

.content {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4d7ef48n/).

Answer (score 0):

there's no 1 line css way to centered div vertically, so you need a workaround, try this simplest one.

```
body {
   position:relative;
}
div {
   position:absolute;
   top: 50%;
}
```

with jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('div').css('margin-top', -$(this).height()/2);
});
```

note: the margin top of the div should be minus half of its height, so in this example, its -50px because its height is 100px.

Comment: Thanks, this is good, except my div is random text gotten from a database so it is variable height....

Comment: maybe you can use jquery to detect the div height and set its margin-top css to half of it

Answer (score 0):

set margin: 0 auto; to the container for horizontal alignment.For vertical adjustment you can use margin-top property.If you require a vertical align than adjustment you can use javascript or jquery. First find the height of the browser window using jquery.Then adjust the margin-top(In a ratio) css property as the window height is changed.You can set an event for detecting the changes of window size.